# Escaped characters in string from submitted form

Tags: php, html, forms, post, escaping

Every time a POST is made I get escaped characters.

```
\ -> \\
' -> \'
" -> \"
```

I have a multistep form, which transmits the data from one form to another. I save the values with prepared statments in the database. The values in the database currently look like `Paul\'s House`. User should have the possiblity to use single and double quotes in their string.

This is a simple example demonstrating the escaping effect:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['value'];
?>
<form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="value" value="Paul's House">
    <input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

Why or who escapes the string? What is the correct way for handling data over multiple forms? What is the correct way for saving it in the database? Should I use `stripslashes()` or I'm opening a big security hole?

Comment: [Magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) are likely your problem. This "feature" is often enabled for old scripts that depend on it. The manual has [several suggestions](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) for disabling the functionality (and you're definitely right to want to disable it).

Comment: `magic_quotes_gpc` is `On`. Will try to change the php.ini settings.

Comment: Three cheers for the latest PHP version actually eliminating magic quotes entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have Magic Quotes turned on.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Check that out for how to disable.

Answer (score 0):

You must turn off the magicquotes in server , otherwise you should very careful about on/off status of the magicquotes .